# Agent Based Reloading

Tags: java, grails

In grails 1.4 roadmap it mentions about Agent Based Reloading , can anyone give some explanations or resource pointers?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implemented as a JVM agent - see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jvm_ti/ for the gory details.

In practice what it means is that in dev mode, instead of using custom classloaders to reload controllers, services, etc., the agent now hot-swaps the recompiled classes. This means that it's no longer limited to grails-app artifacts writen in Groovy. It now works with all classes including src/java and src/groovy which in current versions trigger app restarts when changed.

Also - you can now edit domain classes on the fly. This currently also triggers an app restart but in 1.4 will rebuild the Hibernate SessionFactory and keep running.

Comment: Hi, is this also available to 1.3.7?