# What is the aim of -noreloading grails startup option?

Tags: grails

Can anyone give me some details on grails -noreloading option?

Comment: i cannot find this option in the documention. which grails version are you using? maybe your mentioned option is the same like teh disable.auto.recompile option (Disables auto-recompilation of Java sources, which can be processor intensive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this answer by Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6347134/592139), Grails 2 uses a JVM agent to support reloading of modified files in development mode, in place of the custom classloader used in previous versions.  The `-noreloading` flag is an instruction to the `grails` command line script telling it not to enable this agent when it starts the JVM, and is a useful sanity check when you see unexplained behaviour (while in most cases the agent approach is a big improvement over the old 1.3 approach I have seen various reports on the mailing list of corner cases that interact badly with the reloading agent).